# How to convert Day Month Date time to oracle date ? The format is Wed May 03 00:00:00 IST 2017

Tags: java, date

How to convert, Day Month Date HH:mm:ss time-stamp to oracle date?

The format is : Wed May 03 00:00:00 IST 2017.

I am getting date and time in the format above, I need this format to store it in DB (Oracle) because in the later I have to fetch the date and convert it to corn expression for quartz scheduler.

Comment: You mean you wish to parse this format (say using a `DateTimeFormatter`) and then have a `java.sql.Date` object?

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the question was to convert to a `java.sql.Date` object, the following code shows how to parse the given input.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String inp = "Wed May 03 00:00:00 IST 2017";

    final String parseFmt = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(parseFmt);

    TemporalAccessor ta = dtf.parse(inp);

    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.from(ta);



    java.sql.Date sqlDate = 
            new java.sql.Date(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());

    System.out.println(inp);
    System.out.println(zdt);
    System.out.println(zdt.toInstant());
    System.out.println(sqlDate);
}
```

Output:

```
Wed May 03 00:00:00 IST 2017
2017-05-03T00:00+03:00[Asia/Jerusalem]
2017-05-02T21:00:00Z
2017-05-02
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do as follows

1. Use SimpleDateFormat to parse and get a java.util.Date object
2. Now you can convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Timestamp using java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime())

hope this helps

Comment: Poor advice. Those troublesome confusing poorly-designed classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

## Use objects, not strings

> I need this format to store it in DB (Oracle)

No, you don't.

You do not need strings when working with date-time values. For date-time values, use date-time objects.

## Use java.time

For date-time objects, use only the java.time classes. Avoid the older classes such as java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, and java.sql.Timestamp, as they are confusing, troublesome, and poorly-designed.

Avoid 3-4 letter pseudo time zones such as `IST`. They are not real time zones, not standardized, and are not unique(!). By “IST” did you mean “India Standard Time” or “Ireland Standard Time”? Use [real time zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), named in format of `continent/region` such as `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Dublin`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MAY , 3 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## JDBC

The purpose of JDBC is to mediate between the data types of your database and the data types of Java.

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 or later, you can pass/fetch these java.time objects directly. Use `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.